# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma'

Tags: python-import, metpy

I am trying to plot in metpy with the help of "xarray with MetPy Tutorial". 
For that, I am getting error when am running following modules in:

```
'import cartopy.crs as crs'
'import cartopy.feature as cfeature'
'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt'
'import xarray as xr'
'import metpy.calc as mpcalc'
'from metpy.testing import get_test_data'
'from metpy.units import units.'
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma'

like those errors will appear 
so anyone help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this error with `python 3.7.3` as well. Switching to `Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

My method may be helpful to you.

I was running `Docker Desktop` and `Ubuntu 20.04 Container` on `Windows x64` at the time.

I installing `liblzma-dev` using apt-get firstly, then rebuilt `Python 3.10.9`, and it worked properly. The steps are as follows:

```
# installing liblzma-dev
apt-get install -y liblzma-dev

# prepare Python3.10.9 source and unzip
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.9/Python-3.10.9.tgz && \
tar -xf Python-3.10.9.tgz && \
cd /Python-3.10.9

# configure and compile Python
./configure --enable-optimizations && make -j$(nproc)

# installing Python
make altinstall
```

In general, first install liblzma-dev or other libs in advance, then compile and install Python, and these modules can be used

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with your Python build, rather than with MetPy, as `_lzma` is part of the standard library. From a quick Google search, it seems like this may be an issue with Ubuntu? At any rate, if you google the error, you'll find quite a few solutions to this issue, depending on what your operating system is. We suggest using the Anaconda distribution of Python (https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/), which is easy to set up, and haven't had anyone report this issue before using that stack.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same error and blogged about it [here](https://carl.duevel.online/blog/python_missing_system_deps/). Basically the underscore in the module name hints that it is a module written in C or C++. The reason it is missing from your system is most likely because of a missing system dependencies during installation of the python interpreter. If you installed Python with pyenv [they have documented which dependencies should be installed by plattform](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment). Conda does not have that particular problem as it ships with binary dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed `backports.lzma` via pip after installing debian packages such as `liblzma-dev` and assorted build tools, but it would continue to fail to find the module.

I fixed it by adding a fallback import:

```
try:
    import lzma
except ImportError:
    import backports.lzma as lzma
```

Using python 3.7.