# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma' when building python using pyenv on macos

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, pyenv, lzma

Trying to use pyenv to build python versions on macOS, but every install I make ends up with

```sh
❯ python
>>> import lzma

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma'
```

I have installed all of the following packages:

```sh
brew install openssl readline sqlite3 xz zlib
xcode-select --install
```

Only caveat is that homebrew installs packages to `~/.brew`.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run the code from a file instead of the REPL?

Comment: @AMC I do receive the same error if I run `python my_script.py`

Comment: This exact error seems to be relatively popular: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27532, https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27543, https://stackoverflow.com/q/57371240/11301900

Comment: Yeah, thanks! The typical solution seems to be "install the correct packages before building". Unfortunately, to the best of my knowledge, I have already installed all the relevant packages I could think of (which is why I listed my `brew` history).

Comment: Amusingly enough the last answer from the last link is exactly what I was going to suggest: Forget messing around with pyenv, homebrew, and the system's Python install, and use Conda ;p

Comment: Yeah I'm a long time conda user trying to migrate to pyenv, as it seems to better suit my needs... if I can get it to work 

Comment: _Yeah I'm a long time conda user trying to migrate to pyenv, as it seems to better suit my needs_ That's certainly unexpected, can you elaborate?

Comment: @AMC I had to head out so I missed the chat. Sorry for bailing on you. I ended up figuring my issue.

Comment: @AMC Wanted to say thanks for your help—always appreciated!

Comment: You’re welcome, glad you figured things out :)

Comment: Changing Python version to 3.7 worked for me

Answer (score 151):

None of the prior answers worked for me. The instructions in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/iandanforth/f3ac42b0963bcbfdf56bb446e9f40a33) worked for me.

In short: You may be missing the `xz` libraries, in which case you can install them with Homebrew and then reinstall/rebuild the Python version from `pyenv`:

```
$  brew install xz
$  pyenv uninstall <desired-python-version>
$  pyenv install <desired-python-version>
```

*Note: I only had this problem with the Python installed by `pyenv`, but not the Mac system Python or the `conda` python. It might be best to use the brewed python (`brew install python`) unless you have a specific need for `pyenv` (like needing more control over the python version/updating).*

Comment: This worked for me as well.  Installing xz was the secret sauce.  Thanks!!!

Comment: this worked for me:  ie `brew install xz ` then `pyenv install 3.10.0` in the terminal

Comment: This solved the issue when installing python 3.10.9 on an M1 Mac via pyenv

Comment: Solved the issue, M1 Mac via pyenv.

Comment: Still relevant when installing python versions with pyenv on M2 Macbook.  Thanks!!

Comment: This answer solved the issues on MacBook M2 as well. Thanks!

Comment: Am confirming as this works for M2 Mac as well. Kudos!

Comment: Works for M2 Pro - MacBook 2023 16".

Comment: work perfectly on M2 16" Macbook Pro

Answer (score 32):

Based on [pyenv wiki](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#how-to-build-cpython-with-framework-support-on-os-x), you should install the desired *python* version with `--enable-framework` flag. It did work for me.

```
PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-framework" pyenv install 3.6.7
```

The reason is that the module you're trying to use is implemented in *C*, and *CPython* with shared libs will be built with the aforementioned flag.

Comment: This is what I needed!  Thank you so much!!!

Comment: This did the trick, thanks ! 
In case you already have a pyenv python installed, no need to uninstall first.

Comment: There appear to be issues with some versions of Python and/or OS: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/99

Answer (score 25):

This solved it for me:

```
sudo apt-get install lzma
sudo apt-get install liblzma-dev
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
```

**And** add this files to your current environment:
e.g. (see: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27532#issuecomment-822272237):

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/local/lib/python3.8/
sudo cp /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_lzma.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/local/lib/python3.8/
```

For example, in my runtime environment:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /home/luca/.asdf/installs/python/3.8.10/lib/python3.8`
sudo cp /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_lzma.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /home/luca/.asdf/installs/python/3.8.10/lib/python3.8
```

Comment: This one work for me, But rather than copy manually the  libs, I rebuilt Python after  installing `lzma`.

Comment: I was using Python3.7. I just had to do the 3 sudo commands provided and the comment from @Miguel Angel Retamozo Sanchez

Answer (score 6):

Google always lead me to this thread, but a good answer is in [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1800)

Briefly, you need to do:

```
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix xz)/include" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix xz)/lib" pyenv install 3.9.1
```

If you are a M1 user this will work for you under rosetta.

framework build does not work for me.

Comment: thanks! I think this is essentially the same solution outlined here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59723202/7853533

Answer (score 4):

I solved this on Debian Buster by running:

```
sudo apt install liblzma-dev
```

After that, I recompiled Python.

I'm not an expert with Python, but it appears to have worked.

Answer (score 2):

Ended up figuring out. This issue *only* arose when moving the Homebrew directory from its default. This was not needed when Homebrew was installed normally.

I added this to my `.zshrc` (alternatively, your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`)

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/Users/pcosta/.brew/opt/xz/lib $LDFLAGS"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/Users/pcosta/.brew/opt/xz/include $CPPFLAGS"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/Users/pcosta/.brew/opt/xz/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
```

Homebrew warns that you should do this for other installed packages, but not xz. Presumably, because it is not needed *if* Homebrew lives where it expects to.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work my end. I tried in the terminal to run the export above before adding into the .zshrc file without success. Any other hint?

Comment: [I also have these environmental variables](https://github.com/paw-lu/dotfiles/blob/80dc3eb6e3cc2ac8ac982bbecce97d4b572d0c89/zsh/.zshrc#L287-L307)—homebrew tells you to set them as you install the packages I listed above (`openssl`, `readline`, etc).

I've had this issue again on CentOS, and again it had to do with xz. So that seems to be the main culprit here. [A good first start is to make sure you install the needed packages listed in the wiki page.](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki), then make sure the necessary xz related packages are installed. Are you macOS?

Comment: Thanks I've solve a moment ago, and I didn't realised you answered. I believe the culprit here is the zlib that has to be installed on top of the xz. I can't confirm for sure as I did install a bunch of other things at the same time ```python
brew install automake autoconf libtool pkg-config python zlib freetype libxml2 libxslt xz libyaml
```. But I also later run again a pyenv install xxxx so to foce a new make which eventually did solve the issue.

Comment: This automatically finds the right brew prefix `export LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix xz)/lib $LDFLAGS"; 
export CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix xz)/include $CPPFLAGS"; 
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(brew --prefix xz)/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"`

Answer (score 1):

## Issue 39430?

I don't have an answer. But this symptom sounds like this Python bug ticket:

- [Issue 39430_ tarfile.open(mode=*r*) race condition when importing lzma - Python tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue39430)

Reported in 2020. Unfortunately still unfixed as of 2022.

## Workaround for package "csvkit": Try python2

I experienced this issue when trying to use [package `csvkit`](https://pypi.org/project/csvkit/) on my Windows 10 running MobaXterm:

Package installs just fine but then the /bin/csv* tools don't run:

```
$ /bin/python3 -m pip install csvkit --quiet
✔

$ csvstat --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/csvstat", line 5, in <module>
    from csvkit.utilities.csvstat import launch_new_instance
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/csvkit/utilities/csvstat.py", line 12, in <module>
    from csvkit.cli import CSVKitUtility, parse_column_identifiers
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/csvkit/cli.py", line 16, in <module>
    import lzma
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/lzma.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _lzma import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma'
✘
```

My workaround was to use python2. Not super happy with that.

First throw out the non-working python3 version like so:

```
$ /bin/python3 -m pip uninstall csvkit --quiet --yes
✔

$ hash -r
✔

$ csvstat --version
csvstat: command not found
✘
```

So now it's gone. Let's try again but with python2:

```
$ /bin/python2 -m pip list | grep -i csv
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.3.4; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/bin/python2 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
✘

$ /bin/python2 -m pip install csvkit --quiet
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
  WARNING: The scripts csvclean, csvcut, csvformat, csvgrep, csvjoin, csvjson, csvlook, csvpy, csvsort, csvsql, csvstack, csvstat, in2csv and sql2csv are installed in '/usr/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.3.4; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/bin/python2 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
✔

$ csvstat --version
csvstat 1.0.7
✔
```

Result: csvkit is installed and /bin/csvstat.exe runs without the "_lzma" error. But unfortunately on python2 and not on python3. -- This workaround is kinda good enough for me, because I just wanted the /bin/csv* utilities but maybe useless for people who actually need to run things on python3.

Comment: This worked for me. I had to install python2 and pip2 and then I was able to install csvkit with python2 and it worked as describe above. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the answers here require `brew` for Mac development. If you don't have `brew`, such as when your development environment is managed by `nix`, you can do the following:

- Download the `xz` source from https://tukaani.org/xz/.
- Unzip it to a directory.
- Run `./configure --prefix=~/xz-install` within the directory (you can change the prefix to be wherever you want to be). You may have to make sure the directory exists with `mkdir -p` beforehand.
- Run `make` within the directory (note: you will need xcode command line tools to compile this).
- Run `make install`. This will install to whatever directory you have set with `--prefix`.
- Assuming your `--prefix` directory is set to `~/xz-install/`, install your python with `CFLAGS="-I~/xz-install/include" LDFLAGS="-L~/xz-install/lib" pyenv install 3.10.4` or whatever version you want.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

**frist**

```
yum install xz-devel
yum install python-backports-lzma
pip install backports.lzma
```

**second**

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python3.8
vi lzma.py
```

**finally**
modify about line 27

```
try:
    from _lzma import *
    from _lzma import _encode_filter_properties, _decode_filter_properties
except ImportError:
    from backports.lzma import *
    from backports.lzma import _encode_filter_properties, _decode_filter_properties
```

it‘s work！I had to search for hours to get this problem to be solved.

Credit: [Yolo5 issues](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/1298)

Answer (score 0):

If you installed python via `asdf`, you can reinstall Python like so:

```
asdf uninstall python

asdf install python latest
```

Example output of the `install` command:

```
python-build 3.10.6 /Users/u/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.6
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.10.6.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.6/Python-3.10.6.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.10.6...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
Installed Python-3.10.6 to /Users/u/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.6
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a commodity PC is:

```
sudo apt install libpython3.10-stdlib libpython3.10-testsuite pypy3-lib
```

If you don't want to fill your disk with trash, the first library must work.

Answer (score -4):

### Error Message

```
>>> import lzma
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/lzma.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _lzma import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma'
```

### Solution

Uninstall all versions of Python3. Then reinstall only `python3.5`.

### Original Environment (Environment that has error)

- Linux 4.4.0-62-generic
- Python2.7
- Python3.4
- Python3.5
- Python3.6
- Python3.8

### Current Environment (No error, everything works well)

- Linux 4.4.0-62-generic
- Python2.7
- Python3.5