# How to install Stable Diffusion web UI from AUTOMATIC1111 on a Mac Intel?

Tags: python, macos, artificial-intelligence, stable-diffusion

I've recently tried to use the Stable Diffusion web UI from AUTOMATIC1111 on my Mac Intel. There is no documentation for Mac Intel, and when I tried to use the methods presented for other platforms, I ended-up with a Python exception related to LZMA:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma'
```

I was able to fix the problem thanks to [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59690698/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-lzma-when-building-python-using-pyenv-on). This allowed me to write an installation guide / documentation for Mac Intel that I share in my answer.

My configuration:

- MacBook Pro 2019
- CPU 2,6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7
- GPU Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB
- Memory 32 GB 2667 MHz DDR4
- System macOS Ventura 13.2.1

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask how to install software other than things that are _exclusively_ development tools. Even then, unless the problem is something that wouldn't happen when installing any other kind of software, it's often off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your opinion. The initial problem I had was a Python exception raised when using Stable Diffusion (which is relevant in Stack overflow). I was able to fix it thanks to a Stack overflow post. Sharing my solution, which is this installation guide, seemed to me to be the right thing to do: give back to the Stack overflow community. But if this solution is not welcome, I'll of course delete it.

Comment: I've tried to improve the content of this page following your remark @CharlesDuffy. Hopefully the edited version will be more informative and more adequate to the Stack overflow guidelines. Thanks again for your contribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prerequisites:

- Have `brew` installed
- Have `git` installed
- Have `pyenv` installed
- Know how to use a Terminal

Installation guide:

1. Open a Terminal and move to the directory where you want to install Stable Diffusion web UI.
2. Using the Terminal, clone the stable-diffusion-webui repo. This will create a `stable-diffusion-webui` directory. Once the cloning is done, move into this directory:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui.git
$ cd stable-diffusion-webui
```

3. Using the Terminal, install `xz` with `brew`. Note that this needs to be done before installing Python 3.10:

```
$ brew install xz
```

4. Using the Terminal, install Python 3.10 using `pyenv`. Then set the local Python version to 3.10 in the `stable-diffusion-webui` directory. This will only affect the Python version used within this directory, the default Python version will be unchanged:

```
$ pyenv install 3.10
$ pyenv local 3.10
```

5. Download a Stable Diffusion model checkpoint. I downloaded the 1.5 version (`v1-5-pruned.ckpt` file) from the [Hugging Face website](https://huggingface.co/runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5/tree/main). Then move the checkpoint into the `models/Stable-diffusion` directory.
6. Using the Terminal, run the `webui.sh` script:

```
$ ./webui.sh
```

If everything went fine, you should have in the Terminal a message that looks like this:

```
Running on local URL: http://127.0.0.1:7860
```

7. Open the URL in an Internet browser. In the `txt2img` tab, enter a prompt and click the generate button. This will start the image generation process.

The image I attached to this post was generated on my MacBook Pro Intel.

[image: Image computed using Stable Diffusion web UI]

Comment: when I do " brew install xy", it gave me the error: Warning: No available formula with the name "xy".  What is "xy"?

Comment: Sorry, there's a typo. The package is named `xz`. I'll modify the post right away.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to install [Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os/) first, which takes care of the prerequisites.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. You're right, Anaconda is a good alternative. I've used it for years, but I now prefer to use pyenv + poetry when it comes to Python projects. This is a matter of preference I guess. Thanks again ^^