# why do i can not execute "import lzma" successful in virtual python env create by pyenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv

system

- my system is ubuntu 20.04.
- pyenv 2.3.25-3-g18ed727e

details:

- i use pyenv create a new python version:"pyenv install 3.11.4" and through virtualenv plugin create some venvs base 3.11.4, such as:"pyenv virtualenv 3.11.4 xxx".
- any venv i activate include the base env 3.11.4, i can not "import lzma" successful: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma'.
- this question only appear in the env create by pyenv.

Comment: Module `_lzma` was not compiled by `pyenv`. Most probably because you haven't installed build dependencies: see https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyenv%5D+ModuleNotFoundError%3A+No+module+named+_lzma

Comment: See these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72828943/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/76902857/7976758